# What is meant by the colourful line markings on the left side of the editor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here are a few images showing what I'm referring to. They come in different colours, for example red blue and green below:

###### Red line markings

[image: Red line marking]

###### Blue line markings zoomed in

[image: Blue line marking – zoomed in]

###### Green line markings zoomed in

[image: Green line marking – zoomed in]

###### Line markings

[image: Line markings]

I couldn't find any answer while browsing. It might be because I am unable to search in a right manner.

Comment: I inlined the images and rearranged the order to make the question look better. I put the tall image last as it took the entire screen

Answer (score 1):

These are "diff decorations". They indicate what has changed about a file.

Red means an existing line has been deleted/removed, green means a new line has been added, and blue means an existing line has been modified.

These are all comparing against a previous point in time, which is usually a "commit" in your Source Control Management / Version Control Software of choice (Ex. git, subversion, [VS Code's Local History feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history), etc.)

---

Their display is controlled by the `scm.diffDecorations` setting (SCM stands for "Source Control Management").

If you don't specify a `scm.diffDecorations` setting value, then the default value is "all", which means to display it in the gutter (the sidebar between the line numbers and the text being edited), the minimap, and the "overview" (decorations inside the scrollbar). You can also use the values `"gutter"`, `"minimap"`, and `"overview"` to only display decorations in one of them, or `"none"` to not display them at all.

As you already show in your screenshots, clicking on the decorations in the gutter opens an inline popup showing what has changed and offering action buttons to revert the change.

You may also be interested in the following related settings: `scm.diffDecorationsGutterAction`, `scm.diffDecorationsGutterPattern`, `scm.diffDecorationsGutterVisibility`, `scm.diffDecorationsGutterWidth`, `scm.diffDecorationsIgnoreTrimWhitespace`, and `git.decorations.enabled`.